# Find all the occurrence points of a letter within a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $word = "aeagle";
    $letter = "e";

    $array = strposall($aegle, $letter);

    print_r($array);

    function strposall($haystack, $needle) {
        $occurrence_points = array();

        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            array_push($occurrence_points, $pos);
        }

        while ($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos + 1)) {
            array_push($occurrence_points, $pos);
        }

        return $occurrence_points;
    }
?>
```

As in the example, if I have `aegle` as my word and I'm searching for `e` within it, the function should return an array with the values `1` and `4` in it.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no `$aegle` variable defined in your code. There's `$word`...

Comment: You should consider looking into error logs. Or turn warnings on at least

Comment: Make sure you have warnings enabled in PHP, so you can see you're using an undefined variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're passing the wrong parameters, shouild be $word instead of $aegle

Answer (score 4):

Why not trying instead

```
$word = "aeagle";
$letter = "e";
$occurrence_points = array_keys(array_intersect(str_split($word), array($letter)));

var_dump($occurrence_points);
```

Comment: Nice one, but what if `$word` represents the content of text file, of ...let's say 1 MB? :)

Answer (score 2):

Other's have pointed out you're passing the wrong parameters. But you're also reinventing the wheel. Take a look at [php's regular expression match-all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (whoops, had linked the wrong function), it will already return an array of all matches with offsets, when used with the following flag.

> ***flags***
>
> ***flags*** can be the following flag:
>
> **PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE**
>
> If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of matches into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into subject at offset 1.

Use a single letter pattern for the search term `$letter = '/e/'` and you should get back an array with all your positions as the second element of each result array, which you can then finagle into the output format you're looking for.

**Update:** Jared points out that you do get the capture of the pattern back, but with the flag set, you also get the offset. As a direct answer to the OP's question, try this code:

```
$word = "aeagle";
$pattern = "/e/";
$matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern, $word, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

It has the following ouput:

```
Array
(
  // Matches of the first pattern: /e/
  [0] => Array
  (
    // First match
    [0] => Array
    (
      // Substring of $word that matched
      [0] => e
      // Offset into $word where previous substring starts
      [1] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => e
      [1] => 5
    )
  )
)
```

The results are 3D instead of 2D because preg_match_all can match multiple patterns at once. The hits are for the first (and in this case: only) pattern supplied and are thus in the first array.

And unlike the OP originally stated, 1 and 5 are the correct indexes of the letter `e` in the string `'aeagle'`

```
    aeagle
    012345
     ^   ^
     1   5
```

Performance wise, the customized version of strposall would probably be faster than a regular expression match. But learning to use an in-built function is almost always faster than developing, testing, supporting and maintaining your own code. And 9 times out of 10, that's the most expensive part of programming.

Comment: You get the position of the characters, or the *capture* of that position? Which function would do that?

Comment: Oh, I see. The demo *always* helps.

Answer (score 2):

Little bit more literal than the other answer:

```
function charpos($str, $char) {
    $i = 0;
    $pos = 0;
    $matches = array();

    if (strpos($str, $char) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!!$str) {
        $pos = strpos($str, $char);

        if ($pos === false) {
            $str = '';
        } else {
            $i = $i + $pos;
            $str = substr($str, $pos + 1);
            array_push($matches, $i++);
        }
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

https://ignite.io/code/511ff26eec221e0741000000

Using:

```
$str = 'abc is the place to be heard';
$positions = charpos($str, 'a');

print_r($positions);

while ($positions) {
    $i = array_shift($positions);
    echo "$i: $str[$i]\n";
}
```

Which gives:

```
Array (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 25
)
0: a
13: a
25: a
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but I really like ignite.io. Didn't know about that site before.